# XAML DataGrid Header separator not visible

Tags: xaml

By default the DataGrid ColumnHeader has this weird 3D-ish look which I tried to change by making the background color white. While this worked fine on the 3D-ish effect, the separators vanished.

[Column Header by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nazcf.png)

[Column Header with white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwsqv.png)

Here's it's code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridBuchverzeichnis" Margin="10,160,10,50">

    <!-- Tabellengestaltung -->
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#caecfc" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
            
    <!-- Tabelleninhalt -->
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Autor" Binding="{Binding BuchAutor}" Width="180"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Titel" Binding="{Binding BuchTitel}" Width="350"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ort" Binding="{Binding BuchOrt}" Width="180"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Erscheinungsjahr" Binding="{Binding BuchErscheinungsjahr}" Width="140"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Verlag" Binding="{Binding BuchVerlag}" Width="200"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>



</DataGrid>
```

So, I'm not really sure why it does that. I tried making it visible with the SeperatorVisibility and SeperatorBrush but it's not doing anything.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility" Value="Visible"/>
    <Setter Property="SeparatorBrush" Value="Black"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#caecfc" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Any ideas?